# How to import a file into Carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid, carrierwave, gridfs

So I have an app using rails 3 and mongodb that serves files. I want to import all of the files into gridfs using a runner process without creating new ObjectId's for the files already in the system. Essentially, I want to attach the files using carrierwave to the file object already in the database.

For some reason, when I create a new file document, I can attach a local file without a problem. I can't, however, attach a local file to a document that's been previously created.

I've tried every form of Mongoid's update, and every time I get a method missing or unidentified method.

So for example, this works:

```
somefile = Upload.new(
  :name => "somefile.ext"
)
somefile.upload = File.open("/foo/bar.ext")
somefile.save!
```

But this doesn't:

```
somefile = Upload.first(:conditions => {:name => "somefile.ext"})
somefile.upload = File.open("/foo/bar.ext")
somefile.save!
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can save new file for existing object in this way:

```
somefile = Upload.find_by_name("somefile.ext").first
unless somefile.blank?
  somefile.remove_upload = true
  somefile.save!
  somefile.upload = File.open("/foo/bar.ext")
  somefile.save!
end
```

As you can see,

```
somefile.remove_upload = true
```

means

```
somefile.remove_your_mounted_uploader = true
```